# Customize bash to always include a certain parameter

Tags: bash, shell, ls, alias, parameter

When using the "ls" command, bash prints in the following format:

```
file1 file2 file3 file4
file5 file6 file7 file8
```

But when given the parameter "-1", it prints:

```
file1
file2
file3
```

etc...

Is there a way to somehow "customize" bash to always include the "-1" parameter automatically when using the "ls" command? (I.e. making "ls" equivalent to "ls -1")

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is simply done with an alias;

```
alias ls="ls -1"
```

You can put this in your `.bashrc` file, although it probably already contains the following `alias` to give colourised output:

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto"
```

In which case you would just add to it giving:

```
alias ls="ls --color=auto -1"
```